# Copy files from a folder if they're in another folder too

Tags: bash, file-copy

Considering folderA containing those files:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and folderB containing those:

```
foo
baz
foobar
qux
```

How can I copy `foo` and `baz` from folderA to a new folderC?
Note that I'm comparing only their names, not their contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop over the files. Parameter expansion can be used to extract parts of the path:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in folderA/* ; do
    basename=${file##*/}
    if [[ -f folderB/$basename ]] ; then
        cp "$file" folderC/"$basename"
    fi
done
```

You can loop over files in folderB, too, and I'd recommend it if folderB contains significantly fewer files than folderA.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my bash:

```
echo "Folder A"
ls -l ./foldera/
echo "Folder B"
ls -l ./folderb/
echo "Folder C"
ls -l ./folderc/
read -p "Press any key to start"
duplicates=( "$(find foldera folderb -type f -exec basename {} \; |sort |uniq -d)" )
for file in ${duplicates[@]}; do
cp  "./foldera/$file" "./folderc/$file"
done
echo "Script Finish. Folder C"
ls -l ./folderc/
```

Output:

```
root@debian:# ./bashtest.sh
Folder A
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8230 Oct 14 01:36 abp.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8805 Dec  9 01:58 appslist.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2682 Nov 14 02:50 cpu.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  898 Oct 11 00:25 tkinter-3.py
Folder B
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8230 Oct 14 01:36 abp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  898 Oct 11 00:25 tkinter-3.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  595 Oct 28 00:02 yadlist.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2455 Nov 16 01:24 yadnotebook.sh
Folder C
total 0
Press any key to start
Script Finish. Folder C
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8230 Dec 18 23:55 abp.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  898 Dec 18 23:55 tkinter-3.py
```

Comment: @Patrick Answer tested and updated. Previous answer was wrong. Sorry.